# jQuery: using live() with each()

Tags: jquery

I have this function here:

```
$("a.fancybox_vid").each(function(){
   $(this).fancybox({
    titleShow     : false,
    width:    640,
    height:   395,
    autoDimensions: false,
    overlayOpacity: 0.6,
    href: "misc/mc.php?v="+$(this).attr('id')
  }); 
});
```

Now a link with c lass .fancybox_vid gets appended, and then this will not work. Only if it is there from the beginning. How can I have live() in this each().

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want "live-like" functionality for methods, you can use [the `livequery` plugin](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs):

```
$(function() {
    $('a.fancybox').livequery(function() {
        $(this).fancybox({
            titleShow     : false,
            width:    640,
            height:   395,
            autoDimensions: false,
            overlayOpacity: 0.6,
            href: "misc/mc.php?v="+$(this).attr('id')
        });
    });
});
```

...although it would be better (less overhead) to just call the `fancybox` plugin on the newly created elements.

Comment: the livequery didnt work either. Call the fancybox plugin on the newly created elements, what do you mean by this? That in the appended stuff there should be this follow the jquery $("a.fancybox_vid").each(function(){.. ? Thanks

Comment: @Karem: Sort of. I don't know how you're creating the new elements, but you need to call `.fancyBox()` on the new elements directly. If you do `$("a.fancybox_vid")`, you're actually selecting *all* the matching elements on the page, some of which already have `fancyBox` applied to them. If you update your question to show how the new elements are being created, it would help me tell you how to do it.

Comment: the new elements ( <a id="<?php echo $m[0]; ?>" class="fancybox_vid">video</a> ) is inside in a while loop() (php) and get created if $content contains a youtube video link.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, as `live` handles events. Fancybox only *creates* events on the current element queue.

I think you have to apply the `.fancybox()` method every time you create a new element.

Comment: what do you mean by this? That in the appended stuff there should be this follow the jquery $("a.fancybox_vid").each(function(){.. ?

Comment: Yes, but you don't necessarily have to iterate over each item. Fancybox does that for you. In the last sentence I tried to make clear that you should apply the fancybox after an element was appended: `$(elements).appendTo(document.body).fancybox();`, for example

Answer (score 0):

What about doing a live event, that calls the fancybox:

```
$("a.fancybox_vid:not(.fancy)").live('click', function(){
 $(this).addClass('fancy').fancybox({
  titleShow     : false,
  width:    640,
  height:   395,
  autoDimensions: false,
  overlayOpacity: 0.6,
  href: "misc/mc.php?v="+$(this).attr('id')
 }); 
});
```